# Visualizing values on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

I have a world map shapefile with the country boundary. I want to represent my data associated with specific countries. The values are to be represented in a colour graded manner along with proportional circles. What steps should be taken after I have added my shapefile?

Comment: Turn on the toolbox for labelling and have a look at the diagram options. Also, please be aware that adding diagrams to a "map" greatly reduces the readability of said map. Working with colours and patterns is the preferable option.

Comment: Please check these sources: [Basic Vector Styling](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html) and [Creating a Proportional Symbol map in QGIS 2.18](http://learngis.uk/proportional-symbol-map-qgis-2-18/). To combine them both on one map, just duplicate that shapefile. Have you already done the `JOIN` of your data to that shapefile? Check this [Performing Table Joins](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html)

Comment: No, I haven't joined the data to the shapefile

Comment: Which format do you have those data in?